# VLOOKUP: lookup_value isn't in first column of table_array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

[Microsoft's documentation for VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1) states the following.

> Remember that the lookup value should always be in the ***first column*** in
>   the range for VLOOKUP to work correctly. For example, if your lookup
>   value is in cell C2 then your range should start with C.

Unfortunately, in my spreadsheet the lookup value (*Part Number*) is in column `B`, while the data I want to return (*Supplier ID*) is in column `A`.

**Is it possible to use VLOOKUP if my lookup value is located after my return value?**

[image: VLOOKUP formula]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-A5DCF0DD-996D-40A4-A822-B56B061328BD)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-E8DFFD45-C762-47D6-BF89-533F4A37673A):

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(G12,B:B,0))
```

This will find G12 in column B and return the value from that row in column A.  the `0` means exact match, like `FALSE` in the VLOOKUP.

Comment: To clarify, A:A is the column with return value; PartNumber is the lookup value; B:B is the column with lookup value, and 0 is the lookup array.

Comment: Edited to use your reference

Comment: I'd add a generic version of the formula as well. `=INDEX(return_array, MATCH(PartNumber, lookup_array, [match_type]).` Also, documentation for [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-A5DCF0DD-996D-40A4-A822-B56B061328BD)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-E8DFFD45-C762-47D6-BF89-533F4A37673A)